# phpMyAdmin can't logging by browser

Tags: phpmyadmin, centos7, privileges

I have installed mysql 8.x on Centos my server, i can login into mysql using terminal but i can't login by browser

http://hostip/phpmyadmin

changed AllowRoot false to true.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowRoot']     = TRUE;
```

I have added new user and grant all privileges to new user

flushed it, restarted all services

What else am i missing?
phpmyadmin says " Cannot log in to the MySQL server "

Answer (score 0):

After fresh news installation phpmyadmin wont accept password, need to do that.

ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'PASSWORD';

that was the after few hours solution